# How to remove programs from the start menu windows 7 client using a GPO managed on window server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy

I have a windows server 2008 r2 with a domain where windows 7 desktop pcs connect to.

There are only 3 programs I'd like to display on the start menu for users.

All client computers have the same image, are on windows 7, have the same programs, and are all apart of the domain.

How can i use a GPO to remove all other programs displayed on the start menu and only display this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can individually remove/disable practically everything that's in the Start Menu on a default Windows install through the Group Policy Management Editor through `User Configuration` -> `Policies` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Start Menu and Taskbar`.  Any subsequently installed programs can be removed from the Start Menu via a script (logon script, for example), if you wish.

[image]

Of course, there's a Group Policy Object for literally (?) every item on the Start Menu, so that seems like a pain.

It might be easier handle this with folder redirection. (`User Configuration` -> `Policies` ->  `Windows Settings` -> `Folder Redirection` -> `Start Menu`.)  You can set up redirection for the Start Menu as you wish, and then create your custom, three program start menu in the location or locations you redirect the Start Menu to.

The simplest example being as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Does the path need to be network accessible or does GPO take care of making the data available to computers in the domain?

Comment: @JavaRocky You know, I don't think I've ever tried using a non-network accessible path for folder redirection.  [But the documentation says you can use a local folder, so I'd think you should be able to.](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc786749.aspx)

Comment: just wanted to add that if you set the path of the Start Menu to a location the user does not have access to, the Start Menu (moreover the All Programs list) will be completely empty.